# How to get a value within a bold tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having a table

```
<div class="main">
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>
         <b class="bold">1500></b>
     </td>
     <td>
        <b class="bold">2500></b>
     </td>
     <td>
        <b class="bold">4500></b>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="displayTotal"/>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Get Total"/>
</div>
```

Now on button click I want to add the values within bold tag having class name bold.
I tried using

```
<script>
$('#btnAdd').click(function(){
var a=$("div.bold").Val();
```

I don't know what to do further. Anyone plz help out. I want the result as 8500 within textbox

Comment: your b tags aren't closed </b>

Comment: <b class="bold">1500> should be <b class="bold"> 1500 </b>

Comment: And you code should be $("b.bold") but it will returns a collection

Comment: `.Val();` v should be lowercase other than this there are several other errors too.

Comment: Thanks to all for the wonderful answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your html is not valid. `b` has to close. After you can use an iterator and using jquery `text()` you can get the values and sum them like:

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  //declare a variable to keep the values
  var sum = 0;
  //use each to iterate through b elements
  $("div.main table tr td b").each(function() {
    //sum the values
    sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  });
  //change input value with the new one
  $("#displayTotal").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> <b class="bold">1500</b>

      </td>
      <td> <b class="bold">2500</b>

      </td>
      <td> <b class="bold">4500</b>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="displayTotal" />
  <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Get Total" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer in my opinion.

Comment: Thx Alex actually I had a lot of  code within my html and so here I made a mistake of not putting it correctly. Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
  var a = $('.main .bold').text();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The bolds aren't divs, but 'b's

```
var a=$("b.bold").text();
```